# What to do when I accidentally cancel oracle 19c installation on CentOS

Tags: linux, oracle, centos

Today is my first day using Linux. I was given a task to install OracleDB 19c on our company server running CentOS 8.

When the installation was almost done, the loading bar was at 86% and the title said "completing database creation" I accidentally press "X" and close the program.

Now I wonder, when I come back to the company tomorrow, what I will have to do to re-install Oracle 19c. Will I have to go find and delete thousands of created files, or just simply install the db again and Oracle will overwrite all existed files?

I was following this guide https://oracledbwr.com/step-by-step-oracle-19c-installation-on-linux/ and finished step 13 when the incident occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*" was following this guide"*  I've never understood why people look for some specious 3d-party guide to installation. Why not use the actual, official, [installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/index.html)?

The default installation is actually two separate and distinct operations.  The first installs the oracle software. The second creates a database. When installing I always make the selection to *not* create the database. Once the software is successfully installed, I come back and launch the dbca (DataBase Creation Assistant) to create the database as a completely separate operation.

Since you say that the status was "completing database creation", that means that the installation was completed and the installer had already launched DBCA.  Therefore you do not have to clean up or reinstall oracle.  You only have to drop the incompletely created database.

BTW, you say this is your first to use Linux - implying that you've worked with Oracle on Windows.  But this usage of installer and dbca is really no different.  Once you get to runInstaller, the operation of the installer and dbca is exactly the same on either platform.